# how to each serialize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a problem, I have a field with several forms, these forms can get to repeat up to 50 times but with different values​​, I want to send the form you select from the list with $. post ('process.php', $ ("# form") . serialize (), function (data), but when clicking on a form values ​​are sent only the first form but not send form values ​​to select.

try units themselves, those are two simple documents such

**forms.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejemplo de form con jquery</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("form").validate( {
submitHandler: function(form) {
$.post('process.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
$('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
 <?php

    print "Form enviado correctamente: <br>the post value is <b>".$_POST['name']."</b> ";
?>
```

all I want is that if I put a value to the last form below and I will send you send the value of this form or any you choose, not the value of the form above that there is where the problem is and do not want q send the value of all forms at once ls just want to send the value of the form to select

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear?

Comment: You can't have multiple forms with the same ID. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: I have a field with several forms, these forms can get to repeat up to 50 times but with different values​​, I want to send the form you select from the list with $. post ('process.php', $ ("# form") . serialize (), function (data), but when clicking on a form values ​​are sent only the first form but not send form values ​​to select

Comment: Even if you're generating the form in a loop, you should use a counter variable and give them IDs like `form1`, `form2`, etc. Or give them a common class. But HTML elements can't share IDs, IDs are by definition unique identifiers. Your jQuery selector is matching the first, then not expecting to find anymore, so it stops there.

Comment: You probably need newer versions of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.9/) and the [validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). You should also read the docs on the [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize), since it is probably not coming back in the format you're expecting.

Comment: all I want is that if I put a value to the last form below and I will send you send the value of this form or any you choose, not the value of the form above that there is where the problem is and do not want q send the value of all forms at once ls just want to send the value of the form to select

Comment: hey help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256775/get-location-href-in-a-function-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submitHandler` function receives the form being submitted as its argument, so you can do:

```
  $(function() {
      $("form").each(function() {
          $(this).validate( {
              submitHandler: function(formbeingsubmitted) {
                  $.post('process.php', $(formbeingsubmitted).serialize(), function(data) {
                      $('#results').html(data);
                  });
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

Apparently the jquery-validate plugin does not work properly when applied to a jQuery collection. So it's necessary to use `.each()` to initialize each of them separately.

Comment: the problem is that these forms are in php while and obviously they all have the same id, but each form has a value different post, but select the one you select only sends the value of the first form in the list and I seo to send the form value to select

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. I don't do anything with the ID, so the fact that they're the same is irrelevant in my answer. You should change your PHP to give them different IDs (increment a number and append it to the ID) or not assign any ID at all if it's not really needed (it usually isn't in cases like this).

Comment: I just updated the question, there have 2 examples documents, use them and you know what I mean.

Comment: Does it work if you remove all the `id="form"` attributes?

Comment: no, does not work, use the code that came up, there is complete and test the example, you will see what I want to accomplish

Comment: See the updated code, I've tested this and it works.

Comment: excellent friend, now if I want to change the id to forms that are eg id = formal as write in the code?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The ID isn't used for anything, get rid of it.

Comment: Friend the id of the form of the example is 'form method = "post" id = "form"', now I want the jquery function with form method = "post" id = "formelm" as simple as that.

Comment: Use `$("#formelm")` to target a specific form with that ID. That's basic jQuery.

Comment: how to add the effect $ (".") hide ("slow"), to the function?

Comment: `$(".")` is not a valid selector. Maybe `$(form).hide("slow")` is what you're looking for?

Comment: only be hidden form that submits and not all at once hide

Comment: Maybe you're confused because my variable name is the same as the element tag. I've changed my answer, so now it should be `$(formbeingsubmitted).hide("slow")`. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: hi! i have a new question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256359/how-to-add-effect-hide-slow-to-div-inside-a-php-while

Answer (score 0):

Do not provide the same id to all the forms. You can always serialize each form's data with `$('#formid').serialize();`
And then, you can send it via an Ajax POST.

Or, you can omit the "id" completely, and loop through each form and access it's data using `$(this)`. Since you are trying to send all forms' data at once, you can have a  in each form. And then do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $.each($("form"), function() { 
     $(this).validate({  submitHandler: function() {

            $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {

                    $(this).find('.result').html(data);
                });
        }
     }); });

});
```

Comment: the problem is that these forms are in php while and obviously they all have the same id, but each form has a value different post, but select the one you select only sends the value of the first form in the list and I seo to send the form value to select

Comment: friend, sure you understood the function? because that code you sent me does not work, do not reflect anything in the results div

Comment: I just updated the question, there have 2 examples documents, use them and you know what I mean.