# send a multiple serialize form

Tags: jquery, serialization

I have a problem, I have a field with several forms, these forms can get to repeat up to 50 times but with different values​​, I want to send the form you select from the list with $. post ('process.php', $ ("# form") . serialize (), function (data), but when clicking on a form values ​​are sent only the first form but not send form values ​​to select.

try units themselves, those are two simple documents such

**forms.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejemplo de form con jquery</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("form").validate( {
submitHandler: function(form) {
$.post('process.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
$('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
 <?php

    print "Form enviado correctamente: <br>the post value is <b>".$_POST['name']."</b> ";
?>
```

all I want is that if I put a value to the last form below and I will send you send the value of this form or any you choose, not the value of the form above that there is where the problem is and do not want q send the value of all forms at once ls just want to send the value of the form to select

Comment: all the form's have same `id` change them `class`

Comment: Give me an example of how it can work, there's the test code

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to each serialize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245222/how-to-each-serialize) Please don't re-post the question just because people didn't understand you the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
      $("form").each(function() {
          $(this).validate( {
              submitHandler: function(form) {
                  $.post('process.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
                      $('#results').html(data);
                  });
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hi, i have a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256359/how-to-add-effect-hide-slow-to-div-inside-a-php-while

Comment: hey helpme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256775/get-location-href-in-a-function-load

Answer (score 1):

Add forms with unique name and/or id. Note that the input type changed to button from submit.

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <input type="button" value="SEND"> 
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Nombre</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <input type="button" value="SEND"> 
</form>
```

then wire event handler

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(e)) {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
};
```

Better not to have two elements with the same id in the DOM.

Comment: all I want is that if I put a value to the last form below and I will send you send the value of this form or any you choose, not the value of the form above that there is where the problem is and do not want q send the value of all forms at once ls just want to send the value of the form to select

Comment: The above code submits the form containing the button being clicked. Is that not what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

Give each form a class or same name, then use $(.class).serialize();

And yes you shouldnt have elements in your html that have the same id attr val, defeates the purpose of a unique identifier, bad practice

Comment: ok, and how do I do that? laughingstock a code with which you pass to see if it works