# how to add effect 'hide ("slow")' to div inside a PHP while

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-effects

I have a form that is repeated several times within a div called "formscontainer" in PHP while, I want to make a form submit with their respective div disappears the effect hide ("slow")

here the example code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
      $("form").each(function() {
          $(this).validate( {
              submitHandler: function(formbeingsubmitted) {
                  $.post('process.php', $(formbeingsubmitted).serialize(), function(data) {
                      $('#results').html(data);
                      $ (formbeingsubmitted).hide("slow");
                  });
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php do { ?>
<div id="formscontainer">
  <form method="post" id="form1">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">form </label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
  </form>
</div>
<div id="formscontainer">
  <form method="post" id="form1">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">form </label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
  </form>
</div>
<div id="formscontainer">
  <form method="post" id="form1">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">form </label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"> 
  </form>
</div>
<?php } while ($row_var = mysql_fetch_assoc($var)); ?>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate id names.

Comment: (1) **never** use the same ID multiple times, it won't work, and (2) "desaparesca" is spanish afaik, why not "disappear"??

Comment: it does not matter, but the function is perfectly stinks I want to add the effect to the div with the form you select within

Comment: the id is the same as the form and the div is're inside a potato hile loop is repeated several times

Comment: looks good the sample code and some function works perfectly and hide effect shown also works well but you see that fence dedicated to formbeingsubmitted want this dedicated to the div which is the form

Comment: @Deviandorx check the answer hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("form").each(function () {
        var par_div = $(this).closest('div'); //finding the closest div
        $(this).validate({
            submitHandler: function (formbeingsubmitted) {
                $.post('process.php', $(formbeingsubmitted).serialize(), function (data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                    $(formbeingsubmitted).hide("slow");
                    par_div.hide('slow'); //hide the div
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

you can also use

`$(this).parents('div');` instead of `$(this).closest('div');`

but this `$(this).closest('div');` is faster

Comment: excellent friend, works perfectly, but there is a problem the code I show here is only an example, actual page there are many div tags and I need to specify the div to be granted to the function, example you wish granting div this is <div id="contpro">

Comment: it will work good if you have `<div><form>....</form></div>` means if you have enclosed `<form>` inside a `<div>` and you want to hide that parent `<div>` of the `<form>`

Comment: make use `$(this).parents('div');` if you want `<div><form><div></div></form></div>`

Comment: how do I use $ (this) parents ('div'). ? I'm sorry I have not much experience in this

Comment: hey man i have a other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257242/add-function-inside-a-function-load-post

Comment: hey helpme, pleaee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256775/get-location-href-in-a-function-load